# How to stop (in order to reverse) a fabricjs animation

Tags: javascript, animation, fabricjs

I want to create a mouse rollover effect, like we used to see in flash websites - when the mouse rolls over an element it begins to animate, but if in the middle of the anim the mouse rolls out the animation would stop and run back.

I would like to achieve the same effect with fabric, but I can seem to find a way to stop the animation. For example:

```
rect.animate('top', '200', {
    duration: 1000,
    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
    onComplete: function() {
      //callback code goes here
    }
  });
```

This will animate until the `top` value of the `rect` will become `200`. Is there a way to stop animation before that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify `abort` function.

```
rect.animate('top', '200', {
    duration: 1000,
    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
    onComplete: function() {
      //callback code goes here
    },
    abort: function(){
      return someConditionWhichAbortsAnimationWhenItsTrue;
    }
});
```

The only problem is that `abort` was not passed in to the underlying `fabric.util.animate`, [which I just fixed](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/commit/a64cc65eb6ce262a013c69070ddeb58f49954fc2), so you'll need to use latest version :)

Comment: Thanks! By latest version you mean downloading from the repo?

Comment: @MeLight yep, from repo

Comment: Okay, will do that :)

Comment: @kangax I would appreciate your input for my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283524/how-to-pause-an-animation-in-fabricjs

Comment: Added abort on official documentation. it was still missing after 6 years :D